# Evaluating $\prod_{n=2}^\infty {n^3-1\over n^3+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

> The value of the infinite product $$P = \frac 79 \times \frac{26}{28} \times \frac{63}{65} \times \cdots \times \frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1} \times \cdots$$ is
>
> **(A)** $1$
> **(B)** $2/3$
> **(C)** $7/3$
> **(D)** none of the above

I wrote first 6 terms and tried to cancel out but did not get any idea what will be the last term

I did one same kind of problem $\prod (1-{1\over k^2}),k\ge2$ whose answer is $1\over 2$

here I  think the answer will be $D$, none of this?

Comment: It certainly can't be (A) or (C), since any limit would have to be smaller than $1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: It's easier if you rewrite it as:

$$\prod \frac{n-1}{n+1}\frac{n^2+n+1}{n^2-n+1}$$

Then note that $(n-1)^2+(n-1)+1 = n^2-n+1$.

Comment: i really dont follow the hint, my bad. i m so sorry.

Comment: @Tojamaru: have you encountered telescoping series/products? this is two of them combined.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**
$$
\begin{align}
\prod_{n=2}^\infty\frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}
&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\prod_{n=2}^m\frac{n-1}{n+1}\frac{n^2+n+1}{n^2-n+1}\\
\end{align}
$$
The limit of partial products overcomes the difficulty of multiplying two divergent products that an old answer had.

---

**Telescoping Products**

Look for terms that cancel:
$$
\prod_{n=2}^m\frac{n-1}{n+1}=\frac13\frac24\frac35\frac46\cdots\frac{m-3}{m-1}\frac{m-2}{m}\frac{m-1}{m+1}
$$
$$
\prod_{n=2}^m\frac{n^2+n+1}{n^2-n+1}=\frac73\frac{13}7\frac{21}{13}\frac{31}{21}\cdots\frac{m^2-m+1}{m^2-3m+3}\frac{m^2+m+1}{m^2-m+1}
$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Observe that $$n^3-1=(n-1)(n^2+n+1)\text{ and }n^3+1=(n+1)(n^2-n+1)$$

Again, $\displaystyle (n+1)^2-(n+1)+1=\cdots=n^2+n+1$

Just set a few values of $n$ to find the surviving terms

Comment: That doesn't work, because $\prod\frac{n-1}{n+1}$ has limit $0$ and the second term has limit $\infty$. You have to keep the terms inside one product, or use $\prod_{n=2}^N$ for some fixed $N$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, Please elaborate the statement

Comment: Let $a_n=\frac{n-1}{n+1}$ and $b_n=\frac{n^2+n+1}{n^2-n+1}$. Then $\prod_{n=2}^\infty a_n=0$ and $\prod_{n=2}^\infty b_n=+\infty$. You can't solve this problem by breaking up the one product into two products.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, sorry for the confusion. My question was how to prove the limits

Comment: Ah, well, you can do a telescoping argument to computing $\prod_{n=2}^M a_n$ and $\prod_{n=2}^M b_n$. That gives you $\prod_{n=2}^M a_nb_n$ in explicit form, and then you can compute the limit.