# Find the product of the series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, infinite-product

Can anybody please help me to evaluate the following product?

$$\prod_{n=2}^\infty\dfrac{n^3 - 1}{n^3 + 1} $$

Comment: Calculate the first few partial products. You should spot a pattern not too far in.

Comment: ...please...? And what have you tried?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462082/how-to-solve-this-prod-infty-n-2-fracn3-1n31

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/634973).

Answer (score 7):

Notice $$\frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}=\frac{(n-1)(n^2+n+1)}{(n+1)(n^2-n+1)}$$ and $(n+1)^2-(n+1)+1=n^2+n+1$. Therefore we have a telescoping product

$$\prod_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}=\frac{1\cdot \color{blue}{7}}{\color{red}{3}\cdot 3}\cdot\frac{2\cdot \color{blue}{13}}{\color{red}{4}\cdot \color{blue}{7}}\cdot \frac{\color{red}{3}\cdot \color{blue}{21}}{\color{red}{5}\cdot \color{blue}{13}}\cdots=\frac{1\cdot 2}{3}=\frac{2}{3}$$

If nervous about doing cancelling like this in an infinite product (which is a valid point!), do it carefully for the partial products and end up with the same.

Answer (score 6):

Note that
$$
\frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}=\frac{(n-1)(n^2+n+1)}{(n+1)(n^2-n+1)}=\frac{(n-1)}{(n+1)}\cdot\frac{\big((n+1)^2-(n+1)+1\big)}{(n^2-n+1)}.
$$
We have
$$
\prod_{n=2}^N\frac{n-1}{n+1}=\frac{1\cdot 2\cdots(N-2)(N-1)}{3\cdot 4\cdots N(N+1)}=\frac{1\cdot 2}{N(N+1)},
$$
while
\begin{align}
\prod_{n=2}^N\frac{n^2+n+1}{n^2-n+1}&=\prod_{n=2}^N\frac{\big((n+1)^2-(n+1)+1\big)}{(n^2-n+1)}\\&=\frac{\big((N+1)^2-(N+1)+1\big)}{2^2-2+1}=\frac{N^2+N+1}{3},
\end{align}
and hence
$$
\prod_{n=2}^N\frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}=\frac{1\cdot 2\cdot(N^2+N+1)}{3\cdot N(N+1)}\to \frac{2}{3},
$$
as $N\to \infty$.