# Limit of product with cubes $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{2^3-1}{2^3+1}\frac{3^3-1}{3^3+1}\dots\frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}$

Tags: limits, infinite-product

I am trying to evaluate
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}{2^3-1 \over 2^3+1}{3^3-1 \over 3^3+1}\dots{n^3-1 \over n^3+1}$$
It seems to be the perfect candidate for a factoring formula, however, I get stuck rewriting the fractions. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: This is similar to [How to solve this : $\prod^{\infty}_{n=2} \frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462082/how-to-solve-this-prod-infty-n-2-fracn3-1n31) and [Evaluating $\prod_{n=2}^\infty {n^3-1\over n^3+1}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/634973/evaluating-prod-n-2-infty-n3-1-over-n31)

Comment: Duplicate: [$\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^3-1}{2^3+1}\cdot \frac{3^3-1}{3^3+1}\cdots\frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1009566/201168). (*Found using [Approach0.xyz](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bn%20%5Cto%20%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7B2%5E3-1%7D%7B2%5E3%2B1%7D%5Cfrac%7B3%5E3-1%7D%7B3%5E3%2B1%7D%5Ccdots%5Cfrac%7Bn%5E3-1%7D%7Bn%5E3%2B1%7D%24&p=1)*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One may use a telescoping product, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\prod_{k=2}^n\frac{k^3-1}{k^3+1}=\prod_{k=2}^n\frac{k-1}{k+1} \cdot \prod_{k=2}^n\frac{k(k+1)+1}{k(k-1)+1}=\frac23 \cdot \frac{n(n+1)+1}{n(n+1)}\to \frac23.
$$

Comment: Your last fraction on the right is, I think, upside down.

Comment: $n^3-1=(n-1)(n(n+1)+1)$

Comment: Why is there $3$ in $\frac{2}{3}$ in last expression before limit? In product of $\frac{k-1}{k+1}$ the $3$ cancels, right?

Comment: @AntoineNemesioParras This comes from the second factor: $2\cdot (2-1)+1=3$.

Comment: I deleted my answer because yours became very similar by the time I had finished writing it. However, I see that I already wrote [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/635003).

Comment: @robjohn I started with a hint. Then I completed my hint... But after a second thought, please your clear answer below deserves to be undeleted. I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @OlivierOloa: No problem. I added a bit more to make things clearer so that it might deserve undeletion.

Comment: @OlivierOloa: Good. You got accepted (and my upvote). This is a good answer because it demonstrates the telescoping product.

Answer (score 4):

$$
\begin{align}
\prod_{k=2}^\infty\frac{k^3-1}{k^3+1}
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=2}^n\frac{(k-1)\left(k^2+k+1\right)}{(k+1)\left(k^2-k+1\right)}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\underbrace{\prod_{k=2}^n\frac{k-1}{k+1}}\underbrace{\prod_{k=2}^n\frac{k(k+1)+1}{(k-1)k+1}}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\,\frac{1\cdot2}{n(n+1)}\quad\frac{n(n+1)+1}{3}\\[3pt]
&=\frac23
\end{align}
$$

Comment: This is a neat answer (+1).

Comment: After I wrote this answer, I searched and found that I had written [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/635003), to a very similar question. This answer just finishes the process hinted in that answer.